# Override logback appender-ref from CLI

Tags: logback, spring-logback

I have a logback configuration that for prod and int profiles uses rsyslog appender

```
<root level="info">

        <springProfile name="prod,int">
            <appender-ref ref="SYSLOG7"/>
        </springProfile>
        <springProfile name="default">
            <appender-ref ref="FILE"/>
            <appender-ref ref="STDOUT"/>
        </springProfile>
    </root>
```

This configuration is distributed through hundreds of applications. I need to change it in all applications to stdout. I would be grateful if there was an option to override it in common dockerfile entrypoint (so preferably using some env variable/CLI parameter). Is there something like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ENV variable/CLI parameter:

```
docker run -e LOG_APPENDER=STDOUT your-image-name
```

Note: When you run your Docker container, you can pass an environment variable to specify the appender.

If you have a common Docker entrypoint script that's used across all your applications, you can include logic to read the LOG_APPENDER environment variable and update the Logback configuration dynamically before starting your application. This way, you don't need to modify each application's Dockerfile.

Here's a simplified example of what your entrypoint script might look like:

```
#!/bin/sh

# Check if LOG_APPENDER is set, and if so, update the Logback config
if [ -n "$LOG_APPENDER" ]; then
    sed -i 's|<appender-ref ref=".*"/>|<appender-ref ref="'$LOG_APPENDER'"/>|' /path/to/your/logback.xml
fi

# Start your application
exec java -jar your-app.jar
```